# Convert Array to Hash Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array with the following contents:

```
[["< start >", "The   < object >   < verb >   tonight."], 
 ["< object >", "waves", "big    yellow       flowers", "slugs"]]
```

I would like to create a Hash that would return

```
{"< start >"=>[["The", "< object >", "< verb >", "tonight."]], 
 "< object >"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]}
```

I wanted to do some sort of match key.to_s.match(/< ? >/) but im not sure how to implement..complete noob

Comment: I havent even made one yet, I wanted a hash with that outcome from the array

Comment: More or less what @CarySwoveland posted today/yesterday for an answer: `arr.map { |first, *rest| [first,rest.zip]  }.to_h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to alter your input a bit, but you probably want `Hash#[]` ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)).

Example:

```
arry = [["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]
Hash[arry]
 # => {"key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2"}
```

So you need to massage your array into an array of pairs of keys and values.

```
input = [
  ["< start >", "The   < object >   < verb >   tonight."],
  ["< object >", "waves", "big    yellow       flowers", "slugs"]
]

massaged_input = input.map{|arry| [arry.slice!(0), arry.join.squeeze(" ")] }
 # => [["< start >", "The < object > < verb > tonight."], ["< object >", "wavesbig yellow flowersslugs"]]    

Hash[massaged_input]
 # => {"< start >"=>"The < object > < verb > tonight.", "< object >"=>"wavesbig yellow flowersslugs"}
```

Comment: by altering the array I was able to get this outcome [["<object>"], ["waves"], ["big    yellow       flowers"], ["slugs"]]

Comment: is there a way now to get {<object>"=> [["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]}

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [["< start >", "The   < object >   < verb >   tonight."], 
       ["< object >", "waves", "big    yellow       flowers", "slugs"]]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |(first, *rest),h|
  h[first] = rest.map { |s| s.scan(/\< \S+ \>|\S+/) } }
  #=> {"< start > "=>[["The", "< object >", "< verb >", "tonight."]],
  #    "< object >"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]}.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about this specific example

```
a = [["< start >", "The   < object >   < verb >   tonight."], 
 ["< object >", "waves", "big    yellow       flowers", "slugs"]]

a.each_with_object({}) { |(k,*v), obj| obj[k] = v.map { |a| a.scan(/<\s\w+\s>|\w+/) } } 
#=> {"< start >"=>[["The", "< object >", "< verb >", "tonight"]], 
#    "< object >"=>[["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]]}
```

This just uses a simple regex to parse the strings into the requested format.

[Code Example](https://repl.it/N7H3/6)

Regex: `/<\s\w+\s>|\w+/`

- match `<\s\w+\s>`

  - `<`(literal)
  - `\s` space
  - `\w+` one or more word characters (letter, number, underscore)
  - `\s` space
  - `>` (literal)
- `|` OR
- match `\w+` one or more word characters (letter, number, underscore)

[Regex Example](http://rubular.com/r/IPbnHgx8fb)

Comment: I think something happened during your edit. Your code produces an array of hashes, rather than the hash you show (which I expect is a relic), the latter being the desired return value.

Comment: @caryswoveland thank you edit made to resolve although now essentially duplicates yours

Comment: I figure it's what you intended, so it's mine that's a close dup of yours. Oh, well, the question's closed so time to move on...